# If $0 < p < 1$, then $\int_X \log|f| \,d\mu \le \log \|f\|_p$ using Jensen's inequality

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I think this should be a really simple example of Jensen's inequality,  but I'm really struggling to prove that if $f$ is a positive function such that both $f$ and $\log f$ are integrable, then $\int_X \log f \,d\mu \le \log \|f\|_p$ for $0 < p < 1$ when $X$ is a measure space such that $\mu (X) =  1$. I know I should use the concavity of the $\log$ function but I'm really struggling to see how.

Comment: True for any probability measure $\mu$. Jensen's inquality always requires the measure to be a probability measure.

Answer (score 3):

With no further assumptions, this is false.

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\Omega$ and $X \subseteq \Omega$ such that $\mu(X) < 1$ (hence $\mu(X)^\frac{1}{p}< 1$) as well as $f \equiv 1$ then

$$\int_X \log f \,d\mu = \int_X 0 \,d\mu = 0 > \log(\mu(X)^\frac{1}{p}) =
\log \|f\|_p$$

Comment: Jensen's inequality is always stated for probability measures. I think OP just forgot to mention that $\mu$ is a probability measure.

Comment: Sorry I modified the question, I'm interested in the case where $\mu (X) = 1$
And by the way I'm not sure if there's a difference if $X$ is a general measure space or a probability space. I'm interested in the later